# Deleted files from git cache do not reflect on the remote repository

Tags: git, garbage-collection, push, bitbucket, git-filter-branch

Our git repository is about 600MB because some images got committed by accident. Now we want to delete those images from the repository. As following:

```
$ du -hs .git/objects
606M    .git/objects
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch public/images/upload_xx/" -- --all
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch public/images/upload_xx/" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
$ rm -rf ../.git/modules/flipit_application/refs/original/
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
$ du -hs .git/objects
65M .git/objects
```

On my local system the repo went from 600MB to 65MB. To push it:

```
$ git push --all --force
$ git push --tags --force
```

The changes seem to be pushed to bitbucket but whenever I pull a new clone its still 600MB plus.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You ran `git gc` on your local repo, but it hasn't been run on Bitbucket, so the remote repo there still has those old objects lying around.  Bitbucket runs `git gc` ["automatically on a regular basis based on a variety of triggers"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=287998264).  So next time it runs, you should see the effect on the remote repo (and therefore on new clones of the repo).